# Get random number from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

In a javascript function, I have a multidimension array as below.
How can i get a random number from myObject[1]?

```
    var myObject= [
[ [2,3], [5,9], [4,7] ],
[ [1,3], [5,8] ],
[ [1,2], [5,7], [6,9] ],
[ [5,6], [1,7] ],
[ [4,6], [1,9], [3,7],[2,8] ],
[ [4,5], [3,9] ],
[ [8,9], [3,5], [1,4] ],
[ [7,9], [2,5] ],
[ [7,8], [1,5], [3,6] ]
```

];

Comment: Pick a random number `i` from 0 to 2, and a random number `j` from 0 to 1. Then get `myObject[1][i][j]`.

Comment: That's a really weird set of nested arrays. The outermost array (if it is an array) starts with index `1` and (if it is an array) the `length` will be misleading. But all the others start with index `0`, are definitely arrays, and their `length` will be accurate. I'd be consistent, and also use the much more expressive literal notation throughout rather than only in parts: http://pastie.org/9428838

Comment: Where are you stuck? Which bit do you need help with?

Comment: Did you really mean that you want a random number from `myObject[1]`? If so, why did you tell us about `myObject[2]`, `myObject[3]`, etc?

Comment: T.J Crowder thanks for your suggestion.Actually I just doing a small tic toc javascript game as practice.when user choose to take number1 place will respone one of place from myObject[1] array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work:

```
var randomNumber = getRandom(myObject[1]);

function getRandom(arr) {
   var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * (arr.length)));
   return arr[random1][Math.floor((Math.random() * (arr[random1].length)))];
}
```

Comment: warning! this is untested

Comment: Thanks for your help,but i got "1" as a random number.Actually there is no "1" in my array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function that should do the trick

```
var multiDimNumberPicker = function(inputArray){

    var randomItem;

    //if item is an array
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( inputArray ) === '[object Array]' ) {

        //pick a random item to return
        randomItem = inputArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*inputArray.length)];

        console.log("is still array " + randomItem);

        //process selected item
        return multiDimNumberPicker(randomItem);

    }else{

        console.log("not an array " + inputArray);
        return inputArray;

    }

};

//Generate a random number from myObject[1];
var x = multiDimNumberPicker(myObject[1]);
console.log(x);

//Generate a random number from myObject;
var y = multiDimNumberPicker(myObject);
console.log(y);
```

Example jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rqk5m/1/